# MongoDB (Java) - How to run query saved in javascript file?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

So I have a lot of .js files that I have used to query MongoDB from the Command Line Interface before, but now I want to be able to run those same queries through Java (I am using Java to back a web interface that relies on the information from the query).  How can I use those JavaScript queries from the Java driver and return some data that I can work with (the end game is to format the result into HTML, if that helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to executye your js files during buildtime, you can use [maven-mongodb-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-mongodb-plugin/). This plugin uses db.eval()...

Answer (score 1):

using Java IO to read your js files, filter the queries , execute the queries.

Answer (score 1):

This not possible in an efficient way in current JAVA driver.
Have a look here :
[mongodb java driver - raw command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775921/mongodb-java-driver-raw-command)